How can I use a String Variable to refer to and access properties for a chart control
I have a need to access a charts properties in a module that processes custom labels for 5 different charts using the same routine/module for each chart. The module I created works for the 1st chart but the name of the chart has to change via a string variable passed to change the chart I'm formatting. It's a stream lining thaingy. One label formatting routine for 5 different charts. I tried making a chart array but Vb.net won't do that. I've tried using FindControl method but the IDE didn't like it.
ie.  placeholder = ((Chart)Me.FindControl(txtName & cstr(r))).Text or some such thing.
error msg is chart is not defined or some such thing.
I need to pass a string variable from the call to the mod to sub the chart name so one routine can deal with all 5 charts ... otherwise I have to un streamline and make modules for each chart. I had it all working with all the code in the form body ... now it won't work because the module only has one chart name and cannot change unless it can use a passed variable to change it's name.
VertDeltas649_Chrt_frm.VDeltaChrt1_9.Series(Chart).Points(Number - 1)("LabelStyle") = "Top"
VDeltaChrt1_9 is where the variable needs to go ... an indexed or variable string substitute.
This chart name needs to change from VDeltaChrt1_9 to the next name VDeltaChrt10_19 and the next VDeltaChrt20_29 etc. The variable "Number" is the point index.
Any ideaz will be appreciated
Tried everything suggested here on sub stack.
I was expecting at least one thing to work ... so far no go.
Just found this by trial and error ...
Public ChartName As Control.ControlCollection() ... an array of some sort ?
IDE seemed to accept it as valid code
Then maybe add.controls line of some sort ?
It's probably not important but just wondering if it can be done .... would streamline a lot of my code for this pgm. I'm currently putting things back the way they were.
Even in the form body it would be a handy thing to use a variable string in place of the controls name ... ANY control. I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it but I'm not good enough yet to figure it out. I managed to get label arrays and textbox arrays to go thanks to folks here but some things are still no go.
Awaiting any responses in the mean time.
